# Columnar/Column-oriented database vs wide-column/column family database

Tags: cassandra, column-family, column-oriented, wide-column-store

I got really confused about Cassandra recently because most online material even AWS and Google describe it as columnar database. But actually it is row-based, partitioned, column-family database. Now everything makes sense to me:
Then are all characteristics such as

1. being optimised for foreign join
2. aggregating many rows and a few columns/ single column aggregation
3. Scanning only column by column as opposed to row-based database

still valid or true for Cassandra AKA wide-column/column-family database. 
 **If not, what are their real characteristics? Write Performance?**

**IN addition, I really need a true columnar database example to study on?(as opposed to Cassandra and data are store in different column blocks)**

**Can anyone help? It troubles me for a long time.**
[image]

Comment: This link decribes well: https://www.baeldung.com/cassandra-column-family-data-model#:~:text=Cassandra%20is%20a%20partitioned%20row,and%20removed%20from%20the%20cluster. 
Then I guess cassandra is not good at the characteristics in my question.

Comment: Sadly no one comes to answer it lol